# How to render an .mp3 file URL to play in the browser through PHP & _GET

Tags: php, audio

Normally, if I enter a URL to a media file (such as an .mp3 file) into the address bar, Chrome and Firefox will display a simple player.

`http://example.com/audio/myfile-1.mp3` will normally result in a dark page with a simple web player in the middle, with a play button, and I can listen to the audio file in the browser.

*...The browser does NOT ask me to download it.*

However, when my PHP processes a `_GET` argument, to deliver that file under a different name, it asks to download.

## My situation:

The actual file is located at:

```
www/html/example.com/audio/myfile-1.mp3
```

### No problem

This URL renders with a web player, correctly, with no download request at:

```
http://example.com/audio/myfile-1.mp3
```

### Problem (browser asks to download the file)

| **Browser address** : (not the actual file)

```
http://example.com/aud-1.mp3
```

| **.htaccess** : require mod creates a `_GET`

```
RewriteRule ^aud-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.mp3$ /audio.php?a=$1 [L]
```

...Everything works up to this point...

| **audio.php** :

```php
$id = $_GET[a];

$file = "www/html/example.com/audio/myfile-$id.mp3";

if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="aud-'.$id.'.mp3"');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
  readfile($file);
  exit;
}
```

...Then the browser requests to download the file, but does not render the audio file to play inside the browser. This file is correct, plays correctly, and can be played inside HTML with `<audio>` tags. So, there is no problem with .htaccess or the `_GET` process.

I suppose one of my `headers` must be wrong. Why does the browser ask to download instead of play? What can I do to make the audio file URL play in the browser like other audio files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing this entire Question, I thought to remove the `header('Content-Disposition: ...)` statement, and that solved it. That is the part that makes it download in the browser instead of play.

Any better solutions? Any way to do this better?